# Maven Error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, maven, ssl, keystore

I'm not sure how to react. I was told this is a duplicate question. But only the header is the same - my question is not answered there:
- I am providing a valid cacerts file
- I'm referring to it in the command; no path search
- I'm even providing the password in the command
- I'm doing a ssl trace which says "no file supplied", though I supplied it

I know there are several entries regarding this topic - but I found nothing matching my problem.
I'm using maven (mvn) batch command with windows (not m2e with eclipse) to run clean install or resolve dependencies. Sometimes, when pom.xml was changed, it is necessary to download artifacts from our nexus server.
This used to work for long time for me.

But now the connection to the nexus server (https, the server uses a company owned certificate) fails with "**java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty**"
I know, I changed the Java release. But I'm pretty sure I maintained the cacerts keystore the same way I did with the previous releases. (at leased I compared the fingerprints in both of the cacerts; they are the same).

When running the command 
"**mvn -s  -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djava.net.ssl.trustStore="c:/Programme/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/security/cacerts" dependency:resolve**", the ssl-trace says:

```
keyStore is :    
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: No File Available, using empty keystore.
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
```

I've no idea what I might have changed to get to this trouble. I changed the Windows PATH-Statement, but this should not matter fro the previously described command.
Any hint is appreciated

Comment: I do not see how this question has been answered. I'm providing a valid "cacerts" file and use it directly without searching via any path but it is not found. This situation is not mentioned in the referred question